# how to block missed call notification android

Tags: android

I have developed an app that can block calls and sms from a list provided by the user. But there is a small problem that happens sometimes, especially on a dual-sim mobile phone sets.

Issue ::

- To call a second or two and then there is the ring tone
  disconnected. I do not know why the delay is coming, this is common in
  dual-sim phones, but also for One V I "sometimes" not always.
- Even if the call is blocked in time, the display turns on and displays a missed call notification. I do not want the screen to activate. (this
  occurs in all sets)

how do I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: How did you manage to block calls generally? As far as I know, it is not possible, at least not by public API calls.

Comment: @NikolaTulimirovic I simply reject the call that is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK You can't block miss call notification at least on Android 2.3+. On lower version you can use [this code](https://sites.google.com/site/t2k269group/development-diary/reset-missed-calls-notification). You need a MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission for this.

Comment: yes, you are right, I did a lot of research after posting this question, I ended up with the same answer. Thanks